How to subtract characters from string in Snowflake?
in the database (Snowflake) I have a record that is over 20 characters long.
In order to enable this record as more user friendly, I am trying to shrink it to 15 characters only.
I have a database:
table person
column general_id
Basically the general_id record is as follows:
https://id.x.com/af/a3/192501_Z0B0000000EGZZZ
I would like to remove all these first characters https://id.x.com/af/a3/192501_ so that my output is:
Z0B0000000EGZZZ
Please note the records are different in the db hence I cannot simply use only this single record
Should I use select regexp_replace or any other functions?
Thanks

Your desired output, as shown, has far more than 15 characters. Do you mean you want to only keep the Z0B0000000EGZZZ? If so, why not just keep the right(15) of your column?

I would like to keep last 15 characters (Z to Z)

Add some more sample data, with different cases.

You should point out whether you want to keep a fixed number of characters, to keep everything after the last _ in your string, no matter what length, or something else. Your question is far too vague. And yes, I saw your comment, but that doesn't really answer my question.

I noticed you haven't accepted answers in nearly 4 years. Accepting an answer helps others know the question has been resolved.

Just use the right function if you want to keep the last 15 characters.
with my_data as (
 select '123456789012345aaaaa' as id union all
 select '123456789012345' union all 
 select '123'
)
select right(id, 15) as my_col
  from my_data

Output
my_col
6789012345aaaaa
123456789012345
123

